# How to simulate .Substring() method in Linq-to-Entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have this query:

```
Course c = db.Courses.Find(id);
var pics = from pic in db.PersonnelInCourses
    where pic.PersonnelID == User.Identity.Name &&
        pic.Course.TitleID == c.TitleID &&
        pic.Course.BeginDate.Substring(0, 4) == PersianDateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
    select pic;
```

and I foud out that L2E doesn't support `.Substring()` method. So, how can I get what I want?!

tanx

Comment: Did u get any error??

Comment: yeah indeed! an exception...

Comment: What's your exception? give it

Comment: If it is even remotely possible, change the database and store dates as DateTime. Do any conversion to local calendars in services/UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

```
string year = PersianDateTime.Now.Year.ToString();           
Course c = db.Courses.Find(id);
var pics = from pic in db.PersonnelInCourses
   where pic.PersonnelID == User.Identity.Name &&
       pic.Course.TitleID == c.TitleID && 
       pic.Course.BeginDate.Contains(year)                         
   select pic;
```

thank you all for your help...

Comment: Because! In fact in this prj we have nothing to do with time, and our previously made codes work with string... I know this maybe not a good design, however in some situations the first delivery time is the first priority...

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
Course c = db.Courses.Find(id);
var pics = from pic in db.PersonnelInCourses
    where pic.PersonnelID == User.Identity.Name &&
        pic.Course.TitleID == c.TitleID &&
        pic.Course.BeginDate.Substring(0, 4).Equals(PersianDateTime.Now.Year.ToString()) 
    select pic;
```

I dont know what is the type of the BeginDate?? I it is DateTime, Then call ToString().

Comment: the `BeginDate` is a string itself. nedd to do that?

Comment: Where do u found that L2E does not support substring?

Comment: the exception text! and other posts

Answer (score 0):

The danger with 'Contains' is that it searches the whole string. Depending on how your dates are formatted this could give a problem. E.g: if your date format is "yyyyMMdd" it is unlikely that you will get problems (unless you plan to insert dates before the year 1232). If it is "yyyyMMddHHmmss", expect random and hard to find bugs.

Comment: I don't think that it cause a problem in my case because all of my date formats are yyyy-mm-dd.